# Shortcode Variations?

Tags: functions, shortcode

The function below creates a button when used like so [btn]Button Text[/btn]

```
function btn($atts, $content = null) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array('link' => '#'), $atts));
   return '<a class="btn" href="'.$link.'"><span>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</span></a>';
}
```

I'd like to be able to add two variations to this, color and size which would allow the button to be called with variations, like this: `[button color="teal" size="large"]Button Text[/button]`

But I can't figure out how to do this.  Anybody have a code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function btn($atts, $content = null) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array('link' => '#', 'color' => 'teal' , 'size' => 'large'), $atts));
   return '<a class="btn '.$size.'" href="'.$link.'" style="background:'.$color.';"><span>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</span></a>';
}
```

With that function you get by default color teal and size large. I suppose that for size you are using classess and for color just background. If not the case just leave a space and added it on the class attribute.